# Pygame - Collisions With Floor/Walls

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

Hello I am currently making a survival shooter but cannot find any way on how to do my collisions! I am trying to make the player collide with the floors but with no success. Here is an image of the map (I want to collide with moon blocks):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2apz.jpg

Here is an image of moon blocks with no Background:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9H2m.png

And finally here is my code:

```
    import pygame
import random

gravity = .5
jump_time = 2000
x = 0
y = 0

# Player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, gravity):

        # Player dimensions and position
        self.gravity = gravity

        # Player image and animation
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('images/player.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('images/player2.png'))
        #~ self.images.append(pygame.image.load('ball1.png'))
        #~ self.images.append(pygame.image.load('ball2.png'))
        self.maxImage = len(self.images)
        self.currentImage = 0

        #~ self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 80, 80)
        self.rect = self.images[0].get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.timeTarget = 10
        self.timeNum = 1

        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0

        # Jump and gravity
        self.vSpeed = 3
        self.jumpForce = 15
        self.maxVspeed = 3
        self.isJumping = False

    # Jump inputs
    def handle_events(self, event):

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if not self.isJumping:
                    self.isJumping = True

            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                self.velX = -5

            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                self.velX = +5

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_a, pygame.K_d):
                self.velX = 0

    # PLayer updates
    def update(self, ground):

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

         # Jumping
        self.vSpeed += gravity
        if self.vSpeed >  self.maxVspeed:
            self.vSpeed = self.maxVspeed
        self.rect.y += self.vSpeed
        if self.rect.y >= ground.y:
            self.vSpeed = 0
            self.rect.y = ground.y
            self.isJumping = False
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                if not self.isJumping:
                    self.isJumping = True
        if self.isJumping:
            if pygame.time.get_ticks() < jump_time:
                self.isJumping == True
            else:
                self.isJumping = False
            self.vSpeed -= self.jumpForce

        #print "isJumping:", self.isJumping


        # Animations

        if self.timeNum == self.timeTarget:
            self.currentImage += 1
            if self.currentImage >= self.maxImage:
                self.currentImage = 0
            self.timeNum = 0

        self.rect.centerx += self.velX
        self.rect.centery += self.velY

        # Screen wrap
        if self.rect.right > 1280:
            self.rect.left = 0

        elif self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.right = 1280

    # Player rendering
    def render(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.images[self.currentImage], self.rect)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Zombie():

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/zombie.png')
        #~ self.image = pygame.image.load('ball2.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.direction_left = True

    def update(self, surface_rect):
        if self.direction_left:
            self.rect.x -= 1
            if self.rect.left <= surface_rect.left:
                self.direction_left = not self.direction_left
        else:
            self.rect.x += 1
            if self.rect.right >= surface_rect.right:
                self.direction_left = not self.direction_left

    def render(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Background():

    def __init__(self):

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/arena2.jpg')
        #~ self.image = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def render(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Game():

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        # A few variables
        self.gravity = .50
        self.ground = pygame.Rect(0, 640, 1280, 80)

        # Screen
        size = (1280, 720)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
        pygame.display.set_caption('Moon Survival!')

        # Moon / Background
        self.moon = Background()

        # Zombies
        self.zombies = []
        for i in range(10):
            self.zombies.append( Zombie(random.randint(0,1280), random.randint(0,720)) )

        # Player
        self.player = Player(25, 320, self.gravity)

        # Font for text
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 72)

        # Pause - center on screen
        self.pause_text = self.font.render("PAUSE", -1, (255,0,0))
        self.pause_rect = self.pause_text.get_rect(center = self.screen.get_rect().center)

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        # "state machine" 
        RUNNING   = True
        PAUSED    = False 
        GAME_OVER = False

        # Game loop
        while RUNNING:

            # (all) Events

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    RUNNING = False

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        RUNNING = False

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_p:
                        PAUSED = not PAUSED

                # Player/Zomies events  

                if not PAUSED and not GAME_OVER:
                    self.player.handle_events(event)

            # (all) Movements / Updates

            if not PAUSED and not GAME_OVER:
                self.player.update(self.ground)
                for z in self.zombies:
                    z.update(self.screen.get_rect())

            # (all) Display updating

            self.moon.render(self.screen)

            for z in self.zombies:
                z.render(self.screen)

            self.player.render(self.screen)

            if PAUSED:
                self.screen.blit(self.pause_text, self.pause_rect)

            pygame.display.update()

            # FTP

            clock.tick(100)

        # --- the end ---
        pygame.quit()

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

Game().run()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a very similar game for PyWeek #17 called "Miner".
Here's a screenshot: http://media.pyweek.org/dl/17/powrtoch/miner_ss.png (you can see the similarity!)

You can find the relevant code on GitHub here: https://github.com/marcusmoller/pyweek17-miner/blob/master/miner/engine.py#L202-L220:

```
def checkCollision(self, sprite, xVel, yVel):
    for x in range(len(level.levelStructure)):
        for y in range(len(level.levelStructure[x])):
            block = level.levelStructure[x][y]

            if block is not None:
                if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite, block):
                    if xVel < 0:
                        sprite.rect.x = block.rect.x + block.rect.w

                    if xVel > 0:
                        sprite.rect.x = block.rect.x - sprite.rect.w

                    if yVel < 0:
                        sprite.rect.y = block.rect.y + block.rect.h

                    if yVel > 0 and not sprite.onGround:
                        sprite.onGround = True
                        sprite.rect.y = block.rect.y - sprite.rect.h
```

Comment: If you need some guidance through the code, then please do contact me and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Ok I think I probably will need a little bit of help just for the collisions

Comment: Checking for collisions is pretty much the easiest part thanks to pygame.sprite.collide_rect: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect.
You should also store all your map tiles in a list (or a sprite group) so that you can iterate through the tiles to check if any of them collides with the player sprite.
For optimization purposes, you should only check for collision with the nearest 9 sprites or so. But don't worry about that for now.

Comment: How would I add the tile class to fill the screen and set the walkable and non walkable tiles? (Each is 80x80px)

Comment: You can have a look at my level.py in Miner: https://github.com/marcusmoller/pyweek17-miner/blob/master/miner/level.py

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how to do it. Sorry for the hassle but if possible could you maybe help me with adding it to my code? (Setting the collisions on the moon blocks I want to walk on and no collision on the rest where no blocks are present)

Comment: Sure, could you join #pygame on irc.freenode.net? It'll be easier to communicate there.

Comment: Ok will do that now could you provide a link please?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using [collide_rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect):

```
# See if the Sprite block collides with anything in the Ground block_list
for block in groundBlocks:
    if(collide_rect(player, block)):
         # do not fall
    else:
         # fall
```

where all Block you can walk on are in the groundBlocks list.

Comment: Where abouts would I put the code and blocks list exactly? Thank you.

Comment: You should check for collisions immediately after adding x amount and/or y amount to the rect.x and rect.y of your sprite.