# Collision Detection (Player and Walls)

Tags: python, pygame

i am coding a little game and so on everything is working but there is a problem.

I have no clue how to code a collision detection between my player and the walls.
There must be a way how to check if the player collides with a wall when he goes the step before he does it.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys, random

gameover = False
player_in_radius = False
key_picked = False

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (50, 50, 255)
GREY = (238,223,204)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        super().__init__()
 
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
        
        self.walls = None

class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
 
        # Make a blue wall, of the size specified in the parameters
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
 
        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

        
        

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1200
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 900

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT])
pygame.display.set_caption("EscapefromHoney / ETAGE 0") 

all_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
 
wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
 
wall = Wall(0, 0, 10, 900)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)
 
wall = Wall(1190, 0, 10, 900)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(0, 890, 1200, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

wall = Wall(10, 0, 1200, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)
 
wall = Wall(10, 200, 120, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprite_list.add(wall)

player = Player(50, 50, "pictures\kian60x60.png")
player.walls = wall_list

all_sprite_list.add(player)

while 1:
    if key_picked == False:
        key = pygame.image.load("pictures\key.png")
        keyrect = key.get_rect()
        keyrect.top = 600
        keyrect.left = 480
        screen.blit(key, keyrect)
        
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.rect.y = player.rect.y + 60
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.rect.y = player.rect.y - 60
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.rect.x = player.rect.x + 60
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.rect.x = player.rect.x - 60

    all_sprite_list.update()
    
    screen.fill(GREY)
 
    all_sprite_list.draw(screen)
 
    pygame.display.flip()
 
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

I tried to use this code

```
block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of
            # the item we hit
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
```

but no chance. Still not working. And the other point I dont want the have the whole change thing in it with velocity. I want only steps like i did it in my code.

Comment: Can you please explain how you want it to work?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Wall collision comes up pretty often (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337502/pygame-collisions-with-floor-walls)). Maybe tidy up the code into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score -1):

Your player and your wall are both rects :

Therefore you can simply use the .colliderect() method :

```py
player.rect.colliderect(wall.rect)
```

or

```py
wall.rect.colliderect(player.rect)
```

would both return true if the two rects are overlapping.

If you want more control, simply add a hitbox attribue in your classes which will be a rect of the size you want for the collision detection area and then use the hitbox rect

Happy programming